# Tapping the deep link always redirects to the App Store

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, appsflyer

I implemented Appsflyer OneLink with my cordova(Ionic)application and for android everything works fine.
In iOS, when i run the application directly to the device from Xcode and when i click on a link it opens the application.
But i uploaded the ipa file to Hockeyapp and then downloaded the application and installed and then again i clicked on the link but it redirects to the appstore.

i have added associated domains as well as i doubled checked the team ID as well as other configurations(Universal Links) and they all are according to the documentation.

Any idea about the issue that i am facing here?

Comment: Did you check your **bundle id** in your **adhoc**? And Can you share your **Info.plist** file?

Comment: @Hyuck yes i checked the bundle ID and both are same and no issue with that.

Below mentioned is from the plist.

    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.cardofjoy.userapp</string>

and the came ID is used in the adHoc

Comment: In your **Build settings**, **product bundle identifier** is correct? Sometimes, xcode does not load it correctly.

Comment: Yes.I checked. it was not there as you said. then i added it and rebuild it but still the issue is there.

Comment: Then, I don't have any clues anymore. Sorry...

Comment: I uploaded it to testflight and tested it. But still it didn't work. What i noticed was that in the testfligh dashboard under device requirements, the required capabilities are missing though i have enable associate domains.

Comment: This problem solved after adding release entitlements manually. And also you have to check the automatic sign in in the general tab.

Comment: I have not integrated AppsFlyer SDK. Will it still open App?

Answer (score 1):

If the application does not open as a result of clicking the deep-link in a "Universal Links" scenario, it could be one of the following issues:

- When releasing to HockyApp some credentials that are used by the Universal Link are broken - it could be the `Bundle ID` or the `Development Team Prefix`.
  You can check the credentials available on `https://your-defined-subdomain.onelink.me/apple-app-site-associations` and compare them to the entitlements set in the HockyApp build.
- There is a known "development bug" with Universal Link, which sometimes forces an uninstall of any previous version of the Application, in order for the Universal Link to function properly.

If the issue still persists, you can always open a support ticket with support@appsflyer.com and share more information that could help with debugging this.

Comment: in my case the link was `https://your-defined-subdomain.onelink.me/.well-known/apple-app-site-association.`